# compile expat 2.0.0 with arm-linux-androideabi android ndk toolchain

Tags: c++, linux, android-ndk, expat-parser

I want to build expat 2.0.0 for arm-linux-androideabi with a toolchain from Android NDK. I use Centos 7, x86_64. 
My configure step seems to work

```
PATH=$PATH:/media/qt5-qwt6/tools25/tools
PATH=$PATH:/media/qt5-qwt6/tools25/platform-tools
PATH=$PATH:/media/qt5-qwt6/ndk10/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin
export LD=arm-linux-androideabi-ld
export CPP=arm-linux-androideabi-cpp
export CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
export CXX=arm-linux-androideabi-g++
export AS=arm-linux-androideabi-as
export AR=arm-linux-androideabi-ar
export RANLIB=arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib
export ANDROID_SYSROOT=/media/qt5-qwt6/ndk10/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-4/arch-arm
export CPPFLAGS="--sysroot=$ANDROID_SYSROOT"
export CFLAGS="--sysroot=$ANDROID_SYSROOT"
export CXXFLAGS="--sysroot=$ANDROID_SYSROOT"

./configure --prefix=/home/staff/Desktop/expat_built --enable-shared  --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=arm-linux-androideabi --with-sysroot=/media/qt5-qwt6/ndk10/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-4/arch-arm
```

but at make I get some nasty errors

> /bin/sh ./libtool --verbose --mode=link arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -std=gnu99 -I./lib -I. --sysroot=/media/qt5-qwt6/ndk10/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-4/arch-arm -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -fexceptions  --sysroot=/media/qt5-qwt6/ndk10/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-4/arch-arm -DHAVE_EXPAT_CONFIG_H  -o xmlwf/xmlwf xmlwf/xmlwf.o xmlwf/xmlfile.o xmlwf/codepage.o xmlwf/readfilemap.o libexpat.la
>   libtool: link: arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -std=gnu99 -I./lib -I. --sysroot=/media/qt5-qwt6/ndk10/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-4/arch-arm -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -fexceptions --sysroot=/media/qt5-qwt6/ndk10/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-4/arch-arm -DHAVE_EXPAT_CONFIG_H -o xmlwf/.libs/xmlwf xmlwf/xmlwf.o xmlwf/xmlfile.o xmlwf/codepage.o xmlwf/readfilemap.o  ./.libs/libexpat.so -L/home/staff/Desktop/expat_built/lib
>   /media/qt5-qwt6/ndk10/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: xmlwf/xmlwf.o: incompatible target
>   /media/qt5-qwt6/ndk10/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: xmlwf/xmlfile.o: incompatible target
>   /media/qt5-qwt6/ndk10/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: xmlwf/codepage.o: incompatible target
>   /media/qt5-qwt6/ndk10/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-4/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o:crtbrand.c:function _start: error: undefined reference to 'main'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [xmlwf/xmlwf] Error 1

What do I overlook here? should I change my configure command somehow?

Comment: Save yourself some effort and use a [standalone toolchain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html).

Comment: Thank you for the tip! But what is the diference between using a prebuilt toolchain as I wanted to do and a standalone toolchain? I am asking in regard to 3 programs that are needed for my qt project protobuf, qwt and avahi. Do I have to compile them afterwards with my standalone toolchain?